# Display number based on position in structure hierarchy

Tags: entries, navigation, structure

I'm stuck. For a new site I need to display numbers before the main h1 title and in the submenu's.

**Example:**

- 1 Home
- 2 About

  - 01 history
  - 02 strategy (active page)
  - 03 profile
  - etc. etc.

In the active page (strategy) the title needs to be 02 strategy.
So the number is based on the position inside the parent. If I reorder strategy to the first position, the number needs to be 1.

Can someone help me please?

[preview http://durk.com/example.png](http://durk.com/example.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about using CSS for your numbers? (Yes, this answer makes your question sound a bit off-topic, sorry for that, hehe)

Mainmenu:

```
.mainNav {
  counter-reset: mainNav;
}
.mainNav-item {
  counter-increment: mainNav;
}
.mainNav-item::before {
  content: counter(mainNav) ". ";
}
```

Submenu (double digits):

```
.subNav {
  counter-reset: subNav;
}
.subNav-item {
  counter-increment: subNav;
}
.subNav-item::before {
  content: counter(subNav, decimal-leading-zero) ". ";
  color: gold;
}
```

.

*Edit:*

Misunderstood that `<h1>` problem at first. I don't think that there's a dedicated function in Craft to get the position in a structure.

But you can get the entry position like so. You have to get all the structure entries that are on the same structure level with a new ElementCriteriaModel (→ new DB Queries) and then you do a conditional to find the position of the current entry.

```
{# Get the IDs of all the sections #}
{% set currentSectionId = entry.id %}
{% set allSectionIds = craft.entries.section('myStructure').level(1).ids() %}

{# Define var before loop #}
{% set sectionNumber = '' %}

{# Loop through all section IDs and find the one that matches the current #}
{% for key, sectionId in allSectionIds if sectionId == currentSectionId %}

    {# Use array key to calculate the section's position #}
    {% set sectionNumber = key + 1 %}

{% endfor %}

{# Save the section's position in a custom data attribute #}
<h1 data-section-no="{{ sectionNumber }}">Test</h1>
```

Use CSS to style your heading:

```
h1:before {
  content: attr(data-section-no) ". ";
}
```

Comment: Oh thats smart! I will try it. But how to display the number before the h1 title in the page?

02. hisory

Comment: Use the `mainNav` class on it or modify the CSS to your needs, @Johannes.

Comment: IGNORE that comment, totally misunderstood what you where after @Johannes. See my new edit for that `<h1>` problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a recursive macro to display the site structure. In that macro, when you are looping through the entries `loop.index` will be the the loop index, and `e.level` will be the depth of entry `e` in the structure. Here is a macro to print the navigation.

```
{% macro recursiveNav(entries) %}
{% import _self as self %}
  <ul>
    {% for e in entries %}
      {# loop.index is our index, e.level is our level #}
      <li>
        {# using twig range here to output right number of 0s #}
        {% if e.level > 1 %}{% for i in range(2, e.level) %}0{% endfor %}{% endif %}{{loop.index}}
        {{e.link}}
        {% if e.hasDescendants %}
          {{self.recursiveNav(e.children)}}
        {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endmacro %}

{% import _self as self %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('sitecontent').level(1) %}
{# call recursive nav, pass it level 1 entries #}
{{ self.recursiveNav(entries) }}
```

If all you want is the title for a particular entry (*02 strategy* e.g.), you can use almost the same recursive macro to do that:

```
{% macro recursiveTitle(entries, distinguishedId) %}
{% import _self as self %}
  {% for e in entries %}
    {% if e.id == distinguishedId %}
      {# this is the one we want #}
      {% if e.level > 1 %}{% for i in range(2, e.level) %}0{% endfor %}{% endif %}{{loop.index}}
      {{e.title}}
    {% endif %}
    {% if e.hasDescendants %}
      {{self.recursiveTitle(e.children, distinguishedId)}}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

{% import _self as self %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('sitecontent').level(1) %}
{# call recursive title, pass it level 1 entries and id of our active entry #}
{{ self.recursiveTitle(entries, entry.id) }}
```

There is no way to pass data out of a macro, so the recursiveNav can't also save the index and level of the active entry for later.