# Navigation drop-down problem

Tags: navigation, drop-down

Doing my first site with Craft and UiKit framework I encountered a small problem with dropdown menu. Here is my code:

```
<ul>
  {% set entries = craft.entries.section('spb') %}
  {% nav entry in entries %}
  <li class="uk-parent" data-uk-dropdown>
    <a {% if craft.request.getPath() == entry.uri %} class="active" {% endif %} href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
    {% ifchildren %}
    <div class="uk-dropdown">
      <ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-dropdown">
        {% children %}
      </ul>
    </div>
    {% endifchildren %}
  </li>
  {% endnav %}
</ul>
```

The point is that my child element looks exactly like parent because it takes its structure. But I don't need neither "class" nor "data-uk-dropdown" element...

```
<li class="uk-parent" data-uk-dropdown=""><a href="#">...</a></li>
```

Is there any workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `entry.level` in a conditional:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('spb') %}
{% nav entry in entries %}

    {% set liTagAttributes = entry.level == 1 ? 'class="uk-parent" data-uk-dropdown' : 'class="uk-child"' %}

    <li {{ liTagAttributes|raw }}>
        <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
        {% ifchildren %}
            ...
        {% endifchildren %}
    </li>

{% endnav %}
```

I set a intermediate var to keep the template code clean. If you don't have many levels in your structure, you could also consider to not use the `nav` tag at all and nest your navigation levels using `hasDescendents` and `getDescendents(1)` (see the example code I [posted here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1847/125)).

Comment: Very useful tip! Thank you. By the way, you don't need to use double quotes in `{% set liTagAttributes = entry.level == 1 ? 'class=uk-parent data-uk-dropdown' : 'class=uk-child' %}`

Comment: Errrm, this wasn't for the Twig code but to make it return valid HTML for setting the CSS class, @Stanislav.

Comment: Sure, but if you leave them it returns two times double quotes `""...""`

Comment: Sorry, you were right. HTML5 does indeed allow you to NOT wrap attribute values in quotes.

Comment: @Stanislav forgot to add the `raw` filter to the output. This makes Twig to not escape the code and you end up with single quotes. I definitely don't recommend to use attribute value without quotes at all.