# How do I create a structure side navigation that will show active parent list-item and active child list-item

Tags: structure, navigation, children, parents

A bit of a background on the project. I have a features structure section, that has 2 levels: Parent features & Child features.

`{% set features = craft.entries.section('features').all() %}`

My goal is to get an active class on the parent if the parent page is active or if it's got a child that is active and also get an active class on the child if its active.

The `{% children %}` tag doesn't allow for custom HTML.

I am looking to get something similar to this left navigation. But instead of anchors, each feature will be its own page.
https://craftcms.com/features/all#section-types

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long search and lots of trial and error, I've found the perfect solution!
This is how I created a dynamic structure navigation : parent/child (2 levels deep) with `class="active"` on the parent and the child `<li>`.

```
<ul class="Navigation">

{# Get top-level entries in structure section 'features' #}
{% set parentFeatures = craft.entries.section('features').level(1) %}

{# Loop through top-level entries #}
{% for parentFeature in parentFeatures %}

    {# Check if entry has descendants/children #}
    {% if not parentFeature.hasDescendants %}

        {# List navigation item if entry has NO child entries #}
        <li class="Navigation-item {% if craft.app.request.absoluteUrl == parentFeature.url %}active{% endif %}">
            <a href="{{ parentFeature.getUrl }}" class="Navigation-link">{{ parentFeature.title }}</a>
        </li>

    {% else %}

        {# List navigation item if entry does have child entries #}
        {# Show an active class if it is active or if it contains a child that is active #}
        <li class="Navigation-item Navigation-item--dropdown {% if parentFeature.slug == craft.request.getSegment(parentFeature.level) %}active{% endif %}">

            <a href="{{ parentFeature.getUrl }}" class="Navigation-link">{{ parentFeature.title }}</a>
            <ul class="Navigation Navigation--subMenu">

                {# Get child entries of current iteration's top-level entry #}
                {% set subPages = parentFeature.getChildren() %}

                {# Loop through those 2nd-level entries #}
                {% for subPage in subPages %}

                    {# This is the place where you'd nest the next menu hierarchy !! #}

                    {# List sub-menu navigation item #}
                    <li class="Navigation-item Navigation-item--subMenu {% if craft.app.request.absoluteUrl == subPage.url %}active{% endif %}">
                        <a href="{{ subPage.getUrl }}" class="Navigation-link Navigation-link--subMenu">{{ subPage.title }}</a>
                    </li>

                {% endfor %}

            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

</ul>
```

---

Thanks to **Carlcs**'s old answer about this found here: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1847/6586

Comment: This is interesting. Is this code designed to hide the subnav unless the parent item has child pages? Example: if a parent page with no children is active, will the child pages of another show even though that page is not active?

Comment: @Adam, It is exactly that. I wanted to be able to control everything with CSS. Now I have a way to show the parent/children of whatever page is active. Remember this is a side navigation so I wanted to be able to let the user expand and collapse navigation, similar to the craftcms.com/features/all
And yes, the first if statement checks to see if it has children, and if it does not, it doesn't put class .Navigation-item--dropdown on the parent <li> and doesn't put a <ul> submenu in it.

Comment: Very nice. I need something similar with Craft 4, and your example really helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin that might be doing what you are looking for. You start with building your navigation and put that into a variable. Then you run this through a TwigExtension provided by the plugin "k4navigationCraft3":

```
{% set mainnavigation %}
    {% cache globally using key "main-navigation" %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.section('features').all() %}

    <ul>
        {% nav entry in entries %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
                {% ifchildren %}
                    <ul>
                        {% children %}
                    </ul>
                {% endifchildren %}
            </li>
        {% endnav %}
    </ul>

    {% endcache %}
{% endset %}
```

Then you can use one of the plugins TwigExtensions to do:

```
{{ mainnavigation | k4NavigationGetActivePath(url(craft.app.request.pathInfo)) | raw }}
```

The plugin is named "k4navigationCraft3" and can be found on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/kreisvierdigital/k4navigationcraft3/src/master/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm looking for a way to do this without a plugin and without using {% children %} if possible.